# How do I creat a jquery form validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I am trying to create a dynamic website using `php`. The site is uploaded to a free domain this is my first real world project so I want to put in as best as I can.  I created a modal, in it there is a form and I want this from to validate and without refreshing the page.  but I don't know why my `mail()` is not working please can someone tell me what I am doing wrong.

This is my fixed form inside the modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="form" aria-labelledby="#modalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> 
                </button>
        <h3 class="modal-title " id="modalLabel">Send
          <?php echo 
       $brandName; ?> a message</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <form action="contact_process.php" method="POST" role="form" autocomplete="off" class="form-container">
                <small>
                                        <i class="text-center            
     text-danger">all fields are required</i>
                                    </small>

                <div class="form-group has-danger">
                  <label class="sr-only" for="name">Name
                                        </label>
                  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" class="form-control" id="mail-name" tabindex="1">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group has-danger">
                  <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email
                                        </label>
                  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your E-mail" class="form-control" id="mail-email" tabindex="2">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group has-danger">
                  <label for="tel" class="sr-only">Tell 
         no.
                                        </label>
                  <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Your Phone Number" class="form-control" id="mail-
                phone" tabindex="3">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group has-danger">
                  <label for="message" class="sr-only">
          </label>
                  <textarea class="form-control    
       form-textarea" placeholder="Message" rows="5" spellcheck="true" name="message" id="mail-message" tabindex="4"></textarea>
                </div>

                <input type="button" class="btn  
              btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" value="Cancel" tabindex="5">

                <input id="mail-submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send Message" name="submit" data- submit="...Sending" tabindex="6">
                <p class="form-msg"></p>

              </form>
            </div>
            <!--END thumbnail-->
          </div>
          <!--END col-->
        </div>
        <!--END row-->
      </div>
      <!--modal-body-->
    </div>
    <!--modal-content-->
  </div>
  <!--modal-dialog-->
</div>
<!---modal-->

This is the php form validation in my includes folder:
<pre>
        <?php
       if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     $name = $_POST['name'];
     $email = $_POST['email'];
     $phone = $_POST['phone'];
     $message = $_POST['message'];

     $errorEmpty = false;
     $errorEmail = false;
       $errorPhone = false;

     if (empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($phone) || empty($message)) {
        echo "<span class='err'>Fill in all fields!</span>";
         $errorEmpty = true;
     }

       elseif (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        echo "<span class='err'>Invalid email please make sure you enter a 
        valid email address!</span>";
        $errorEmail = true;

    }
      elseif (!preg_match("/^(\d[\s-]?)?[\(\[\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\)\]\s-]{0,2}?
     \d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}$/i",$phone)) {
          echo "<span class='err'>Please enter only a valid phone number!
     </span>";
          $errorPhone = true; 
      }

    else{

        // add resipeants
        $to = "danjumashiwaju@gmail.com";

        // create subject
        $subject = "$name sent you a message from www.djshumzy.com";

        // construct a message 
        $msg = "Name: $name\r\n";
        $msg .= "Email: $email\r\n";
        $msg .= "Tell: $phone\r\n";
        $msg .= "Message: \r\n$message";

        $msg = wordwrap($meg, 70);

        //set mail header
        $headers  = "MINE-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=1so-8859-1\r\n";
        $headers .= "From: $name <$email>\r\n";
        $headers .= "X-priority: 1\r\n";
        $headers .= "X-MSMail-priority: High1\r\n\r\n";

        mail( $to, $subject, $msg, $headers);

      } if (mail === 1) {
        echo "<span class='suc'>Thank You!...Your Message has been Sent !
      </span>";

        }   


       }
       ?>

      <script>
      $("#mail-name, #mail-email, #mail-phone,               
        #mail-message").removeClass("input-error");

    var errorEmpty = "<?php echo $errorEmpty; ?>";
    var errorEmail = "<?php echo $errorEmail; ?>";
    var errorPhone = "<?php echo $errorPhone; ?>";

    if (errorEmpty == true) {
        $("#mail-name, #mail-email, #mail-phone, 
        #mail-message").addClass("input-error");
    }

    if (errorEmail == true) {
        $("#mail-email").addClass("input-error");
    }
        if (errorPhone == true) {
        $("#mail-phone").addClass("input-error");
    }

    if (errorEmpty == false && errorEmail == false && errorPhone == false) {
        $("#mail-name, #mail-email, #mail-phone, #mail-message").val("");
    }
     </script>

    </pre>
```

Here is my jquery validation(.js)

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var name = $("#mail-name").val();
    var email = $("#mail-email").val();
    var phone = $("#mail-phone").val();
    var message = $("#mail-message").val();
    var submit = $("#mail-submit").val();
    $(".form-msg").load("includes/contact_process.php", {
        name: name,
        email: email,
        phone: phone,
        message: message,
        submit: submit
    });
  });
 });// END FORM VALIDATING
```

Please what do I have to do to make this from submit to emails and validate at the same time.

Thus the form validates but it does not send the email and just gives an error message instead.

Comment: So, before solve any problem, better do your best in a correct way, Don't combine `php` with `html`. *1st step!*

Comment: *2nd step!* Easily use [jQuery Validation Plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Use https://jqueryvalidation.org/

```js
$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true
    },
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true
    }
  },
  messages: {
  field: "Please Enter Your Name",
  email: "Please Enter Your Email Address"
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/site-demos.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>


<form id="myform">
<label for="field">Enter Name : </label>
<input type="text" class="left" id="field" name="field">
<br/>
<label for="email">Email Address: </label>
<input type="text" id="email" name="email">
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Validate!">
</form>
```

This jQuery plugin makes simple clientside form validation easy.